# How to aggregate until a certain value is reached in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I would like to aggregate a list of documents (each of them has two fields - timestamp and amount) by "amount" field until a certain value is reached. For example I would like to get list of documents sorted by timestamp which total amount is equal to 100. Is it possible to do in one query?

Here is my query which returns total amount - I would like to add here a condition to stop aggregation when a certain value is reached.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "timestamp": {
                        "gte": 1525168583
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "total_amount": {
        "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
        }
    }
},
"sort": [
    "timestamp"
],
"size": 10000
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Please note that `sort` and `size` have nothing to do with aggregations, only with the hits that are returned. So it's unclear what results you'd like to see. Can you show some mock example of what you'd like to see?

Comment: Yes I know, You can ignore them sorry.

Comment: Still, I'd like you to explain with an example what result you'd like to see. Do you want the total per hour/day/... not to exceed 100? or get the set of documents ordered by timestamp up to their total amount reaches 100?

Comment: I would like to get a list of documents ordered by timestamp up to their total amount reaches 100.

Comment: The answer is: no, it's not possible. Aggregations do not affect the query itself, sorting or limiting the result set's size. They are applied to _all_ the documents matching the query (irrespective of "size" value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible using a combination of [function_score scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) for mimicking sorting, [filter aggs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) for the range gte query and a healthy amount of [scripted_metric aggs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) to limit the summation up to a certain amount.

Let's first set up a mapping and ingest some docs:

```json
PUT summation
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_second"
      }
    }
  }
}
POST summation/_doc
{
  "context": "newest",
  "timestamp": 1587049128,
  "amount": 20
}

POST summation/_doc
{
  "context": "2nd newest",
  "timestamp": 1586049128,
  "amount": 30
}

POST summation/_doc
{
  "context": "3rd newest",
  "timestamp": 1585049128,
  "amount": 40
}

POST summation/_doc
{
  "context": "4th newest",
  "timestamp": 1585049128,
  "amount": 30
}
```

Then perform the query:

```json
GET summation/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1585049128
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "function_score": {
                "query": {
                  "match_all": {}
                },
                "script_score": {
                  "script": {
                    "source": "return (params['now'] - doc['timestamp'].date.toMillis())",
                    "params": {
                      "now": 1587049676
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "limited_sum": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": """
                state['my_hash'] = new HashMap();
                state['my_hash'].put('sum', 0);
                state['my_hash'].put('docs', new ArrayList());
            """,
            "map_script": """
              if (state['my_hash']['sum'] <= 100) {
                state['my_hash']['sum'] += doc['amount'].value;
                state['my_hash']['docs'].add(doc['context.keyword'].value);
              }
            """,
            "combine_script": "return state['my_hash']",
            "reduce_script": "return states[0]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```json
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "filtered_agg" : {
      "meta" : { },
      "doc_count" : 4,
      "limited_sum" : {
        "value" : {
          "docs" : [
            "newest",
            "2nd newest",
            "3rd newest",
            "4th newest"
          ],
          "sum" : 120
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've chosen here to only return the `doc.context`s but you can adjust it to retrieve whatever you like -- be it IDs, amounts etc.